# How does copying/passing instances of a WebDriver work, and is it dangerous?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I've been working on a team that's been developing a Selenium WebDriver infrastructure for a few months now, and something about the way we access the driver object from test cases and page objects is bugging me.

Our test cases create a new WebDriver instance and open the browser. This new instance is stored in the test case class.

Then, the test case instantiates a page object. Following along with [Selenium's Page Object Pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects), these page objects take the WebDriver as a parameter in their constructor (though I notice in our version it isn't final). The various page object methods use the driver that was set in the page object's constructor to do what they do. If a page object method navigates to a new page object, then the WebDriver is passed on to it. Just like in Selenium's example:

```
public class LoginPage {
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;

        // Check that we're on the right page.
        if (!"Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
            // Alternatively, we could navigate to the login page, perhaps logging out first
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the login page");
        }
    }

    // Conceptually, the login page offers the user the service of being able to "log into"
    // the application using a user name and password. 
    public HomePage loginAs(String username, String password) {
        // This is the only place in the test code that "knows" how to enter these details
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).submit();

        // Return a new page object representing the destination. Should the login page ever
        // go somewhere else (for example, a legal disclaimer) then changing the method signature
        // for this method will mean that all tests that rely on this behaviour won't compile.
        return new HomePage(driver);
    }
}
```

This makes it seem as though the WebDriver instance is unique and important, like a torch that must be passed from page object to page object. The style of the code led me to think that I always had to make sure I was using the same instance of the driver that was used in the last operation.

But this "passing of the torch" becomes complicated or impossible with situations where there are multiple page objects on a page, and page object methods don't return the page object that you are planning on working with next. How can you operate on the same WebDriver instance when you've got two page objects on the screen, and you need to alternate between them, without switching to a new page or creating new page objects?

All this confusion leads me to believe that no passing of the torch is actually necessary, or maybe even happening (are all these page objects storing references to the same WebDriver instance?), but then I don't know why that pattern was suggested in the description given by Selenium.

So, do I need to worry about "passing the torch?" Or will any page object operate fine once instantiated with its WebDriver, even if other page objects perform operations with their own versions of the same WebDriver in the interim?

Would it be easier/better to just make the WebDriver a singleton, accessible to all, since we won't be using more than one WebDriver per JVM at any given time? Then we wouldn't need to pass the WebDriver around in constructors at all. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: well, in my project I've got the following structure:
BaseSeleniumTest.java which is extended by other classes  (containing set of tets with @Test annotation). So in BaseSeleniumTest.java I declare WebDriver driver;   as static variable and in that way I avoid creating multiple webDriver instances.

Comment: Just to put this out there, there are some cases where you would want multiple webdriver instances if you literally need to work with two separate browsers for a given use case.

Comment: "... then I don't know why that pattern was suggested in the description given by Selenium."  Can you provide a link to this?  My recollection was that they passed a WebDriver instance to static methods.

Comment: It wasn't an explicit suggestion really, but the suggestion is in the code that I posted. The loginAs method is part of the LoginPage, which gets a driver from somewhere when it is created. The loginAs method returns a HomePage, which is passed the driver from LoginPage. So in your test, you create a driver, pass it to your first page object (like LoginPage), and then LoginPage passes it to HomePage, etc. It gives the impression that the driver _must_ be passed along from page object to page object, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to mark the webdriver as a singleton for the entire framework. I had been currently using this pattern and it works fine. 
  **Note: Care should be taken when dealing with parallel execution.**

@CodeEnthusiastic
For example take a class `GeneralLibrary`, in that create a `WebDriver`.

Extend the classes in Page Object Model with `GeneralLibrary` as super class

Comment: I would definitely like to use a singleton, especially if the WebDriver actually does maintain some sort of state information that makes it imperative that all page objects and operations use the _same_ WebDriver.

I don't _think_ we plan on doing parallel execution on the same machine, with the same JVM. My experience so far with Selenium makes me worry that it's too fragile to do that - I'd worry about actions on one browser messing up execution on another.

Comment: @rironin, Each webdriver instance is associated with a session id , which can be assumed as random generated 32 bit key. So one browser actions doesn't affect other at all

Comment: It makes sense that one browser wouldn't affect the other at all directly, but doesn't IE especially have problems with running automation when the IE window isn't in focus? Do all automation calls function equally well if the browser window is covered by a different browser window, if the browsers are minimized, etc? I feel like it'd be impossible to guarantee that the browsers being operated on would have focus or would be visible if you were running multiple tests simultaneously on the same machine.

Comment: @rironin, Selenium is purely based on the browser instances created. but not on the browser area covered/minimised/maximized

Comment: @Automation_User Can you please provide snippet or a link to make WebDriver a singleton in your answer?

Comment: Well, just one more question, whether it has to be static or static final. I really do not understand how are we exactly creating a singleton using the approach, we are not making the GeneralLibrary singleton so how could we say that just putting Webdriver and instantiating in a super class can be called Singleton?

Comment: @Automation_User I have created a class in which I have instantiated WebDriver, and I have other two classes which extend this class, is that it? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @Automation_User - you can't really do that.  a proper page object might already be extending LoadableComponent and so you can't also extend a utility class at the same time.